# System lockup or crash after message "failed to start guix-publish.service"

Tags: boot, command-line, kde, 23.04

Ubuntu Studio 23.04 upgraded from 22.10 in the past 2 weeks.
23.04 is faster and seems way more stable than 20.04 and 22.04 once up and running.
It is the getting to the log-in screen that is a challenge.
The challenge being an unrecoverable system halt before the keyboard connection becomes active.

#### Process

1. I select Ubuntu Studio in grub-2.
2. first 4 or 5 messages that have been there since 20.04 and declared "just irritating" and "ignore-able" appear.
3. A new failure message displays [FAIL](In Red) Failed to start guix-publish.service - Publish the GNU Guix store. While this message may not indicate the cause, whatever is causing the system halt immediately follows.
4. The display is static.

   - There is no response from keyboard clicks.
   - The Numlock light is extinguished.
   - Pressing [Numlock] does not change keyboard functionality.
5. There is no change *after 15 minutes*.
6. On the assumption of an unrecoverable system halt I hold the computer power button.
7. After a few moments I press the computer power button.

   Note: what follows is also **what I expect to observe** instead of what I observe in steps 3 through 6 above.
8. I select Ubuntu Studio in grub-2.
9. first 4 or 5 messages that have been there since 20.04 and declared "just irritating" and "ignore-able" appear again.
10. The failure message displayed previously is present but in some cases absent.
11. After some seconds the cursor appears mid screen.
12. After another short delay the log-in screen displays.
13. Log-in is normal,
14. Operation after log-in is normal.

#### My research efforts and request for guidance.

Revision, 2023-08-20:
I am going to follow the instructions in these two seemingly better and clearer sites to gather more and better information to add here. Also to see if this would be better posted as a bug report on launchpad.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DebuggingSystemCrash
(last edited 2015-06-23 11:54:47 by 28)
Note:  DebuggingSystemCrash has one broken link.
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysrq.txt
This returns "404 Not Found           nginx" and a search within   https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ for "sysrq" returns no matches. I will notify them via Ubuntu Quality Team ubuntu-quality@lists.ubuntu.com regarding that.
and
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/CrashdumpRecipe?action=show&redirect=KernelTeam%2FCrashdumpRecipe
(last edited 2021-11-04 14:04:59 by tomreyn)

If anyone knows of more recent or relevant procedures site for Debugging a System Crash I would appreciate a comment.
I apologize as I am a technical illustrator and very poor at command line work when I do not have very-clear step-by-step instructions I can copy and paste.
Given the foregoing, I am very willing to follow any instructions given or referred to and present the results in hopes of helping making Ubuntu Studio the best it can be.

#### Platform information.

Operating System: Ubuntu Studio 23.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.104.0
Qt Version: 5.15.8
Kernel Version: 6.2.0-1010-lowlatency (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: Wayland
Processors: 24 × AMD Ryzen 9 7900X 12-Core Processor [Using X.Org X Sever Nouveau (Open Source) as recommended.]
Memory: 31.0 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: NV172
Manufacturer: MicroElectronics
Product Name: G905
System Version: 1.0